# How to remove square bracket from a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one column is having a list of values, how to remove the list?

Input dataframe:

[image]

Output should be:

[image]

Comment: you could convert it to string and then format it however you like it, but I'm not sure that's the best way about it

Comment: you could add a more descriptive title? "Removing square brackets" is not the most ideal description? you already know you want to turn a list into a string with the contents of the list only

Answer (score 3):

Use custom lambda function with `if-else` for join values of lists converted to strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['data1','data2','data3'],
                   'Column2':[['a','b','c'], 20, [14,35,50,20]]})

print (df)
  Column1           Column2
0   data1         [a, b, c]
1   data2                20
2   data3  [14, 35, 50, 20]

f = lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].apply(f)
print (df)
  Column1      Column2
0   data1        a,b,c
1   data2           20
2   data3  14,35,50,20
```

Comment: A bit late here but have been struggling to find the answer for a similar problem, your answer worked perfectly! Thanks alot